# std::out the outer dimension of a 2d char

Tags: c++

Create a console application with the following code (renaming f to your entry point):

```
#include <iostream>
void f(){
    char a[5][5];
    std::cin>>a[0]>>a[1]>>a[2]>>a[3]>>a[4];
    for (int y = 0; y<5; y++)std::cout<<a[y]<<'\n';
}
```

and input 5 lines of 5 characters such as :

```
abcde
abcde
abcde
abcde
abcde
```

I expected the output to be identical to the input or throw an error, but instead I got:

```
abcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcde
abcdeabcdeabcdeabcde
abcdeabcdeabcde
abcdeabcde
abcde
```

When investigated using the debugger, each `a[y]` value is equal to `abcde` and not the displayed output.
What on earth is going on here? *Why* is this happening, and is there a way to stop it?

Is it related to the

> Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted

Error that gets thrown after it `std::cout`s?

---

I'm well aware of other ways to get the desired output using nested loops, but I'm wondering if there's a way to iterate only the outer dimension so it uses fewer characters - this is for a code golf challenge. It makes quite a difference:

`for(int y=0;y<5;y++)std::cout<<a[y]<<'\n';`

vs

`for(int y=0;y<5;y++){for(int x=0;x<5;x++)std::cout<<a[y][x]}std::cout<<'\n';`

Comment: you are in the realm of undefined behaviour. To store a string of `n` char, you need to reserve `n+1` char, since C strings need a NULL terminator.

Comment: @jaunt   You are trying to output the arrays as strings however they do not contain strings because there is no room for the terminating zero.

Comment: check with debugger a[y] before and after executing cin>>a[y+1], you will notice something weird, since the latter command will overwrite the previous char[5] null terminator. As R Saku says in its answer, using `string` instead of plain char array (and vector instead of plain array[]) will make your life much easier.

Comment: @GianPaolo Ahh okay, makes sense then to get that strange output. As this was for a code golf challenge I know the exact input format and using `char` uses less characters, but yes I would otherwise use `std::string`s!

Comment: @Jaunt, optimized code is hard to write, hard to maintain, and often prone to errors like your one. before optimizing, (such saving 5 bytes of memory in this case or a few picoseconds in other scenarios), ask yourself if you really need this kind of optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that you are trying to store `"abcde"` in a char array with 5 elements. You need at least one more element in the array to hold the terminating null character.

As a consequence, your program has undefined behavior. We can try to make sense of the output but it's futile.

Use

```
char a[5][6]; // Anything greater than 5 will work for your input
```

If you don't want your code to be tied to a hard coded size, you can use `std::string`.

```
std::string a[5];
```

Comment: Wow I'm surprised we have to explicitly allocate room for the terminator, surely it's clear to the compiler that it's needed?

Comment: @jaunt, The size information is lost when the function where the data is read to the string gets called.

Answer (score 1):

A C-string is an sequence of characters that ends with a null terminator.  That means `"abcde"` is actually 6 characters long, the 5 you see plus the null terminator.

Since you only allocated enough space for the input without the  null terminator trying to put the string into the array writes off the end of the array and is undefined behavior.  What you need is

```
char a[5][6];
```

As that will have enough space for the 5 characters plus the null terminator.